# How to compress the following in scala?

Tags: scala

my code :

```
val result= rdd.filter(x=> x.get[DateTime]("mytime") > offsetvalue._1 && 
             row.get[DateTime]("mytime") <= offsetvalue._2)
```

I would like to compress the code like:

```
val result = rdd.filter(x => myFunction())
where myFunction() {x=> x.get[DateTime]("mytime") > offsetvalue._1 && 
             row.get[DateTime]("mytime") <= offsetvalue._2 }
```

when  myFunction is call it is showing exeception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1476) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:300) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
at com.aruba.sparkjobs.apprf.LeaderBoardJob.runJob(LeaderBoardJob.scala:203) ~[ee507b50-011f-42de-8bd5-536ca113d640-2015-09-25T11:11:23.637+05:30.jar:1.0.0-b.3]
```

How to serialize the above function

Comment: you can simply pass myFun() to filter.  val result = rdd.filter(myFun()), But you need to modify your myFun() like giving type of x.

Comment: What do you mean by minimize?

Comment: I approve of putting complex expressions like this in separate functions - it can make much more readable code, especially when you come back to  it after a while. However, it would require a better function name than `myFun`!

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
def resultFilter(offsetValue: (A, A)) = (x: B) => {
  val date = x.get[DateTime]("mytime")
  date > offsetValue._1 && date <= offsetValue._2
}

rdd.filter(resultFilter(offsetValue))
```

where you have to fill in `A` and `B` because there's not enough information in your question to infer them.

Comment: @spk that's a question for you. `A` is the type of the values in `offsetValue`, whereas `B` is the type of the elements inside your `RDD`.

Comment: By `let`, do you mean `val`? ( `let`is haskel isnt it ? )

Comment: @gabriele-petronella 

        val result : Rdd[CassandraRow]= rdd.filter(
        row => myFunction(row, Offset))

when function is calling am getting error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but you could make your expression more readable this way:

```
val (min, max) = offsetValue
val result = rdd.map(_.get[DateTime]("mytime"))
  .filter(t => t > min && t <= max)
```

and here's a direct answer to your question:

```
def myFun(x: YourType): Boolean = {
  val (min, max) = (dateTime1, dateTime2) // the values from offsetValue, assuming they are constant
  val t = x.get[DateTime]("mytime")
  t > min && t <= max
}
```

and then you call it as

```
val res = rdd.filter(myFun)
```

Comment: Task not serializable exception found How to resolve it